# Pass the address of a specific array element to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

I'm working on this palindrome function and I'm trying to modify it so that I can send a specific location in an array as a starting point.
Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
bool pali(int [],int size);
int main()
{

   int n[] = {3, 5, 9, 4, 8, 2, 8, 4, 7, 10}; //just a sample array for testing
   int length = 10;
   pali(n,length);
}

bool pali(int a[],int size)
{
  int flag=0;
    int i=0;
    while(flag==0 && i<size){
        if(a[i]==a[size-i-1]){
            flag=0;
            i++;
        }

        else{
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How can this code be altered to take specific element addresses. So that if I send it the location of the array address at say `3` with a size of 5, it will return true (as in 4, 8, 2, 8, 4).  But if it is sent another address and size that isn't a palindrome it returns false.

Comment: You already have 2 arguments in your function, just use the same method to add 2 more?

Comment: If you're using C++ do try and use `std::vector` instead of C-style array plus `size` pairs. Also avoid `using namespace std`. It's intended to be kept separate to avoid collisions with your own code. You can also `return flag == 0` or `return !flag` if you want to return a boolean, or even better, make `bool flag = true`, invert the meaning, and avoid casting.

Comment: @the_martian  Just write  pali(n + 3, 5 );

Comment: Thanks everyone, super helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pointer can point to any element of an array (assuming compatible type of the pointer). Just like it can point to the first element of an array, it can as well point to another element.

Pointer arithmetic can be used to calculate the address of an element of an array. Adding integer i to a pointer will result in a pointer to the i'th successive sibling of the originally pointed object. Knowing that the name of an array will decay to the pointer to first element, we can calculate the address of the element at index 3 of the array `n` with the expression `n + 3`.

As such, the function needs no modification, since you can already pass it the address of any element.